# Bluetooth on Debian on a Toshiba Satellite C50-B

Tags: debian, drivers, bluetooth

I've installed `firmware-linux-nonfree`, but I still can't use Bluetooth. All of the programs (e.g. `bluetoothctl`) complain about there being "no default controller" whenever I try to do anything related to Bluetooth.

The label on the laptop says "intel inside" so I tried installing the `firmware-iwlwifi` package; that doesn't seem to have done anything.

How do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This took a while to find the solution to. I eventually found the solution on Debian Forum .DE:

> Aber ist die richtige Firmware bei [firmware-atheros](https://packages.debian.org/search?searchon=names&exact=1&suite=all&section=all&keywords=firmware-atheros) denn dabei? ich habe da auf die schnelle nix von AR9565 gefunden.  — [debianoli](https://debianforum.de/forum/viewtopic.php?t=156366#p1050089)

Translated (badly):

> But is the right firmware in [`firmware-atheros`](https://packages.debian.org/stable/firmware-atheros) doing it? I found here in the AR9565 quick 'nix.

To conclude: despite not reporting itself to Debian as an Atheros Bluetooth Radio, nor being listed in the laptop's specification, the `firmware-atheros` package contains the magical ability to make the C50-B's Bluetooth radio talk to Debian.

Answer (score 1):

I have a Toshiba Qosmio X505-8104X which has bluetooth and wifi built-in.  Both the wifi and the bluetooth were working fine on Debian 9, but after upgrading to Debian 10, the bluetooth functionality quit working.  I then spent several hours searching the web for solutions, and nothing worked.  The Bluetooth settings page (Activities / Settings / Bluetooth) would allow me to turn it on at the top, but the content of the page would continue to say that it was off, and it never tried to scan for devices.  I'll list all the things I tried here, so that you can ensure that you (at least) have the same packages installed, and then I will tell you what FINALLY got it to working.

**NOTE:  This info might also be useful to you if your system, like mine, combines the wifi and the bluetooth support TOGETHER into a single component.**

**FIRST OF ALL,** DO NOT BOTHER trying to get Toshset (independent Toshiba Settings utility) installed and working.  It may install, and may appear to help some of the functionality of the machine, but if you try to use it to adjust bluetooth settings, it will probably tell you that the required toshiba kernel is not available.  Besides, it is so ABSOLUTELY outdated and no longer maintained that it is probably more trouble that it is worth.  I'm a developer, so I even went as far as trying to get it to compile.  That was a waste of time.

**This next step is very important.**  Examine your system for a hardware switch which turns on/off the wifi and/or bluetooth transceivers.  There are soft(ware) switches (software controlled), and on some system, there are also hard(ware) switches. The hardware switches tend to work in more of an "airplane mode" capacity, so ensure that this switch is on while you are trying to get the bluetooth transceiver to work.  **You are not done yet!**  You may also have a "function key" soft(ware) switch associated with these transceivers.  On this machine, I have them all!  I can turn the hardware switch on, but if I don't press Fn+F8, then it might still be turned off.  Be sure to try out the various positions of each of these switches.

Now, install the following packages via a terminal window as follows:

```
sudo apt-get install bluetooth bluez bluez-utils rfkill
```

Other bluetooth packages were already installed, such as gnome-bluetooth and blueman, but honestly, I can't tell that they do anything useful.

You will want to do a full/hard reboot of the system after installing any of these packages.  If you are still in the terminal window, you can make this happen by entering the following command.  (The zero tells it not to delay in shutting down.)

```
sudo shutdown 0
```

The *rfkill* utility you just installed, can provide access to additional soft switches that you may not be seeing.  Get the status of your radio frequency (rf) kill settings by executing the following command:

```
sudo rfkill list
```

In *most* cases, this utility can make you aware of the settings of both hard and soft switches.  We really want to see the word "no" beside each of the switches that it finds, telling us that nothing is being blocked.  However, since all of these reported "no", this still did not point out the issue with my machine.

If the *rfkill* utility shows that your bluetooth system is blocked, issue the following command to see if it can *unblock* it:

```
sudo rfkill unblock bluetooth
```

Some people will tell you that your device is dead if you run the command below and do not see anything listed which contains the word "bluetooth", **but this is not necessarily true!**

```
sudo lsusb
```

It is nice if you see something in the list indicating a functioning bluetooth device, but in my case, it was not definitive.

Make sure that the bluetooth service is running by executing the following command:

```
sudo service bluetooth status
```

If it is not running, start it by executing the following:

```
sudo service bluetooth start
```

**Do not be overly alarmed** if you see items in red when you run either of the two previous commands.  There are several reasons why a partial failure might be reported.  In all the cases I have seen, the red content was informing me of features/support missing from some of the devices that the transceiver saw.  It also reports failures when certain items go to sleep.  What can be **really** confusing at first, is that your transceiver may report on these devices even though it is not paired or connected to them.  In my case, my headset was paired successfully, but had gone to sleep, causing it to report **Unable to connect Headset Voice gateway** or **Connecting Headset Voice gateway failed.**

I was to the point of giving up on getting the built-in bluetooth radio to work, and was shopping on Amazon for a replacement dongle, when I started wondering if the wifi portion of the device was still functioning.  I use a wired connection most of the time, so I hadn't even tried the wifi portion of the component.

The Bluetooth settings window was up when I clicked on the network icon in the top-right corner of the screen.  The Bluetooth settings window still showed that it was off.  I clicked on the item *Wi-Fi Not Connected*, and then selected one of my wireless access points to cause it to connect.  It connected just fine.  I then clicked the item to turn it off again.  Upon doing so, I noticed the Bluetooth settings screen refreshed and it began searching for devices!!!  **Somehow, the action of connecting and disconnecting the wifi, cleared whatever issue was preventing the bluetooth from working, and the problem has never returned.**

As a software developer, I hate encountering an issue such as this which cannot be easily duplicated.  Nevertheless, they happen, and are often the hardest bugs to fix.  Hopefully, this works for at least one other person, and I can save you some of the time that I spent resolving this for myself.